# Alter Table Auto Increment starting number criteria from another query or field

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a database that stores all our distribution partner sales. Every week I get updated sales that I load into what I call tblImport. I then have some queries I run that parse out new sales lines to tblUpdate and tblNewAccounts. What I am struggling with is automating what I call the Bill To ID(BT_ID) field in the NewAccounts table. I know how to find the highest BT_ID from the master customer table. What I cannot figure out is how to get the tblNewAccounts to start auto numbering the BT_ID field with the max BT_ID +1 from the master customer table.

I figured out Alter Table and here is the code I used in an SQL Query that works but I need the value 128071 to actually be 1 plus the MAX BT_ID from the Master Customer Table.

```sql
ALTER TABLE [tblUpdate2_NewAcct]
ALTER COLUMN [BT_ID] AUTOINCREMENT(128071,1)
```

Here is something else I tried but I keep getting errors.

```sql
SELECT Max(tblALX_BillTo.BT_ID) AS MaxOfBT_ID
FROM tblALX_BillTo;
ALTER TABLE [tblUpdate2_NewAcct] ALTER COLUMN [BT_ID] AUTOINCREMENT([MaxOfBT_ID],1);
```

I have tried doing this in VBA as well and it hasn't worked either. I am assuming it all has to do with that criteria field for the start of AutoIncrement.

Comment: Access cannot process multiple SQL in one construct (unless it is a PassThrough query to a backend like SQLServer). Could try DMax() domain aggregate function in place of the static reference. I am not understanding why an autonumber in tblNewAccounts is dependent on a key in another table.

Comment: Yes. It is an empty table when I want to assign the seed value for autonumber. I want to assign that first, then populate the table with the new customers from the import table.

Comment: also, the key in the other table is the primary key for all customers. No duplicates allowed. It is not AutoNumber because the numbering always comes from the NewAccounts table. The reason I do it this way is because I actually have 4 different sources for sales data. This is my primary source though, so it is used the most. Because of that I want to automate as much as possible because of the size of the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With fairly easy VBA code, you can use `DMax` to grab the maximum current `BT_ID` value plus 1.  Then write that value into your `ALTER TABLE` statement, and execute it.

```vb
Dim strDDL As String
Dim lngNewSeed as Long
lngNewSeed = DMax("BT_ID", "tblALX_BillTo") + 1
strDDL = "ALTER TABLE tblUpdate2_NewAcct" & vbCrLF & _
    "ALTER COLUMN BT_ID AUTOINCREMENT(" & lngNewSeed & ", 1)"
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strDDL
```